# if checkbox is checked in html table then i want to update the value of that row when update button is pressed

Tags: php, css, html

this is my fetched table and i have added check box to every row now i want to update this table if specific field is checked so kindly suggest me something`while($record=mysql_fetch_array($res)){

```
echo "<tr align='center'>";
echo "<td>".$record['YourName']."</td>";
echo "<td>".$record['FatherName']."</td>";
echo "<td>".$record['RegNum']."</td>";
echo "<td>".$record['Gender']."</td>";
echo "<td name='$i' >".$record['MobileNumber']."</td>";

echo "<td>".$record['Password']."</td>";
echo "<td>".$record['specialist']."</td>";
echo "<td>".$record['area']."</td>";
echo "<td>".$record['building']."</td>";
echo "<td>".$record['room']."</td>";
echo "<td><input type='checkbox' name='$i' value='Bike' align='center'></td>";
echo "</tr>";

$i++;
```

Here is fetched data and the check box.

[image: Picutre]

Answer (score 2):

your design need to be changed, do something like

```
echo "<tr align='center'>";
echo "<td>".$record['YourName']."</td>";
echo "<td>".$record['FatherName']."</td>";
echo "<td>".$record['RegNum']."</td>";
echo "<td>".$record['Gender']."</td>";
echo "<td name='$i' >".$record['MobileNumber']."</td>";

echo "<td>".$record['Password']."</td>";
echo "<td>".$record['specialist']."</td>";
echo "<td>".$record['area']."</td>";
echo "<td>".$record['building']."</td>";
echo "<td>".$record['room']."</td>";
echo "<td><a href='edit.php?id={you id for record}'>Edit</a></td>";
echo "</tr>";
```

it will look like
[image]

Answer (score 0):

jQuery is your solution. Take a look at [this page](https://api.jquery.com/checked-selector/)

You can implement it like in [here](https://api.jquery.com/checked-selector/)

> ```
> $(document).ready(function() {
> //set initial state.
> $('#textbox1').val($(this).is(':checked'));
>
> $('#checkbox1').change(function() {
>     if($(this).is(":checked")) {
>         var returnVal = confirm("Are you sure?");
>         $(this).attr("checked", returnVal);
>     }
>     $('#textbox1').val($(this).is(':checked'));        
> }); });
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Since, Database Table structure is not provided. I am assuming : *Primary Key* & *Auto-Increment* column name as `user_id`. (Change it, if you having other column name).

```
<form method='POST' action='approve.php'>
    <table>
        <?
        $i=1;
        while($record=mysql_fetch_array($res)){
            echo "<tr align='center'>";
                echo "<td>".$record['YourName']."</td>";
                echo "<td>".$record['FatherName']."</td>";
                echo "<td>".$record['RegNum']."</td>";
                echo "<td>".$record['Gender']."</td>";
                echo "<td name='$i' >".$record['MobileNumber']."</td>";

                echo "<td>".$record['Password']."</td>";
                echo "<td>".$record['specialist']."</td>";
                echo "<td>".$record['area']."</td>";
                echo "<td>".$record['building']."</td>";
                echo "<td>".$record['room']."</td>";
                // Pay Attention Here in this checkbox. 
                echo "<td><input type='checkbox' name='Approve[]' value='".$record['user_id']."' align='center'></td>";
            echo "</tr>";
        $i++;
        }?>
    </table>
</form>
```

**approve.php**

```
<?php
$countApprovedCheckbox = sizeof($_POST['Approve']);

for($i=0;$i<$countApprovedCheckbox;$i++) {

    $userID = $Approve[$i];

    $query = "UPDATE TableName SET ApproveColumnName='Approve' WHERE user_id='$userID'";
    //Execute Your Query Here.

}
?>
```